# Python-SocketIO server won't emit from the main section of the program

Tags: python, socket.io, emit

I have a pyhton-socketio server that servers on port 8000 and handles connections perfectly. I want to emit the following emit message every 2 seconds. When emitting the client doesn't receive a message. If I emit from where I point out in the comment it works perfect.

**How can I edit this to be able to emit from inside the while loop successfully?**

The python server code:

```
import socketio
import eventlet
import threading
import time
from flask import Flask, render_template

sio = socketio.Server()
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


# as a decorator:
@sio.on('connect')
def connect_handler(sid, environ):
    print('IP->' + environ['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    # If I emit here it works e.g. sio.emit('status-update', {'core0_in': 8, 'core1_in': 12,'cpu_usage_in': 5, 'users': 7})


@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)


class Server(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = thread_id

    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.name)
        serve()


def serve():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        global app
        # wrap Flask application with socketio's middleware
        app = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)

        # deploy as an eventlet WSGI server
        eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 8000)), app)


server_thread = Server("Server-thread")
server_thread.start()
while True:
    print("Emitting...")
    sio.emit('status-update', {'core0_in': 8, 'core1_in': 12,'cpu_usage_in': 5, 'users': 7})  # when emitting here the client doesn't receive anything
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: time.sleep(2) is outside of your while loop. That's not going to get hit.

Comment: I made mistake in the question. Edited. @LaneL

Comment: How do you even know you are connected to the client within the while loop? Did you try moving your loop into your connection handler? To me it would make more sense to start a thread with your loop after the connection has already been established.

Comment: I explained in the question that I can connect inside the connection handler. The problem was I wanted to do it elsewhere.